# how to wrap text in ionic?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

My code is working with several ion-item elements. The problem arises when I run the code, the ion-item tag is causing the text in the card to be chopped off and trailed with a "..." at the end.

Here's something that it looks like.

```css
.card {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-card class="card">
      <div id="labels">
        <ion-label>
          This is a paragraph. It is meant to demonstrate how ionic doesn't wrap the text when it's too long.
        </ion-label>
      </div>

    </ion-card>
  </ion-item>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ionic itself has a css class to wrap text, nowrap or justify. you can use this as per your requirement with your class. no need to manage this in your css class.

> class="ion-text-wrap"

**Please check the below link for more details**

https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities

Answer (score 0):

1- Remove display: inline-block; from the style.
2- Bring div tag inside ion-label tag.
3- break your string in your code to display it properly.

Comment: `Break your string in your code` I'm not sure I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code in your global.scss file if you want to wrap the label text in all of your pages. If it is for a single page, add this code in the respective scss file.

```
ion-label {
white-space: normal !important;
}
```